# Add each number in array to every other number in array

Tags: objective-c, macos

How can I add every object, which is an NSNumber object to every other NSNumber object in the array and add the sum object to a new array?

e.g.

```
array1 has numbers 1, 2, and 3.
then do:
1 + 1 = 2 then add 2 to array2.
1 + 2 = 3 then add 3 to array2.
1 + 3 = 5 then add 4 to array2.

2 + 1 = 3 then add 3 to array2.
2 + 2 = 4 then add 4 to array2.
2 + 3 = 5 then add 5 to array2.

3 + 1 = 4 then add 4 to array2.
3 + 2 = 5 then add 5 to array2.
3 + 3 = 6 then add 6 to array2.

So array2 has 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6.
```

I can handle the removal of the duplicates. I've tried putting a for loop within another for loop which would essentially do what I had outlined above but I have over 28,000 numbers which are not the numbers 1 - 28,000. It took over a very long time to compute since there are 28,000^2 possible sums. Surely there must be another way. Can anyone please elaborate?

Comment: So you're saying you can't have duplicates? That would make a big difference in the algorithm

Comment: @Merlevede It doesn't matter for me. Duplicates are ok, as long as it doesn't take like three hours.

Comment: What did you try then?

Comment: @Wain I'm pretty certain I mentioned what I tried.

Comment: I meant show your code. Did you think about multi-threading? Why are you trying this on a mobile device??

Comment: @Wain It's not on a mobile device, it's on my Mac and its a Mac app.

Comment: I've corrected the tags then. Try implementing multi-threading up to the number of cores on the machine

Answer (score 1):

If you have a set of N random numbers and have to add each to each other, I would not be sure that this is not O(N²).

Computing all numbers leads to 784.000.000 sums before uniquing them. Using 32 bit integers (not NSNumber instance objects) the memory footprint would be almost 3 GB.

You have to implement this lazy ("every sum on demand")

Comment: Good point. Suppose you do this algorithm for consecutive numbers 1..100. There are 49 combinations with result=100. If results are added on a Dictionary or a collection that strips duplicates the amount of memory could be drastically improved, but maybe the lookup time is a drawback.... just some thaughts!

Comment: Yes, with a different problem a different solution is possible. "I have over 28,000 numbers which are not the numbers 1 - 28,000." However, doing close to 1 G calculations and object creations is that slow that obvious ricks like "reducing it a bit" would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe

```
NSMutableArray *myNewArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSUInteger length = myArray.length;  // or size?? I don't remember 
for (NSUinteger i=0; i=0<length; i++)
    for (NSUinteger j=i; j=0<length; j++)
        [myNewArray addObject:([array objectAtIndex:i] + [array objectAtIndex:j])];
```

Here the secret is the initial condition in the inner `for` loop `j=i`. For example, since you have already done the sum for 1+2 you don't need to do 2+1 anymore, hence duplicates are not included, although you could still have duplicate results (e.g. 3+4 = 7; 1+6 = 7).

Instead of having n^2 sums, you have n*(n+1)/2 sums... almost half of it!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this right now. Also, in the last line of your code, do you mean to have one of the `objectAtIndex:i` to be `objectAtIndex:j`? BTW it's myArray.count :)